# PostgreSQL Input Parameter as Type of Column and Array?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm attempting to use a `postgres` `stored procedure` akin to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.sp_get_transaction_recurrences(
    p_transactions IN "transaction".id%TYPE
)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
    BEGIN

    END;
$procedure$
;
```

with the `p_transactions` parameter as an `ARRAY` of the `TYPE` identified from a table column type.  Is this possible or would it have to be instantiated with something like `BIGINT[]` instead of `"transaction".id%TYPE`?  If it is possible, what is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.sp_get_transaction_recurrences(bigINT[])
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
    BEGIN
    END;
$procedure$;
```

call it by:

```
call  public.sp_get_transaction_recurrences('{1,2,3,4}');
```

update: You cannot do that> https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo
It's a todo...

Comment: I'm asking for a solution that uses the `"transaction".id%TYPE` style in place of `BIGINT`.

Comment: @CoryG https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo....

Comment: thanks, found it in https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo#PL.2FpgSQL - looks like it's unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

It looks so this feature is not supported. You cannot to make an array type from type of referenced object.